# Box Number of Number VBA Bartender

Tags: vba

I've just been asked to try and figure out some VB code to accomplish the following in Bartender;

I essentially want to create a field that looks at a quantity, and then increments a number based on the number of copies of that label.

So basically we'll have 1 of 2, 2 of 2, 1 of 3, 2 of 3, 3 of 3, etc, etc

We have a workaround that involves selecting only certain lines of the data to print, and doing this for each individual line, as the first number (i.e the "1 of" number) just continually increases based on the number of copies, so regardless of the second number, it will keep increasing (i.e 1 of 2, 2 of 2, 3 of 3, 4 of 3, 5 of 3, etc).

I imagine the code will look something like this;

```
FirstNumber.Value = 1
For Each Copy
FirstNumber.Value = FirstNumber.Value + 1
Loop Until
FirstNumber = SecondNumber
Goto Next Copy and repeat event
```

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks guys!

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything with Bartender, but isn't there an api available to work with it unless I'm very much mistaken, in which case you could use vb.net as opposed to vbscript, always a better option.

Comment: vb.net and vba is not the same language.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you want to do with the strings when you have created them; the following code displays them in a MsgBox (you will need to change that line to do what you want). It's also not clear if you want a vba or a vb.net solution; the following code is for vb.net and would need to be adjusted for vba (remove "As Integer" from the for statements and ".ToString" from the MsgBox text).

```
For numMax As Integer = 1 To 4
    For num As Integer = 1 To numMax
        MsgBox(num.ToString & " of " & numMax.ToString)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I accidentally added the vb.net tag, it should be VBA! I want the resulting number to display in a text box and increment with each copy. I will try this in the morning, as it's not my PC who currently has access to Bartender annoyingly. Thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end;

On the NewRecord event, I set the value of to 0, and on the IdenticalCopies event, I set Value to Value + 1.